# Match Current date with CSV file and print the matches

Tags: python, date, csv, datetime, smtp

hi so im writing a python script to send a birthday mail kind of thing . But im stuck in middle . i Have a csv file containing names and there birthdays and already wrote a code to get the current date ,

```
#Import Date
import datetime
CurrentDate = datetime.datetime.now().date()
CurrentDate = CurrentDate.strftime("%d-%B-%Y")
print(CurrentDate)
```

and my csv file is

```
user1,13-September-2016
user2,19-October-2016
user3,13-September-2016
user4,25-August-2016
```

So what i want is match current date with the second column of this csv and Get the corresponding column one value and export them as a string like i got the CurrentDate from datetime . If there's more than one user havind birthday on corresponding day an "and" should print between their names . I Hope i didn't make any mistake asking the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group them in a list and output whatever you want:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now().date().strftime("%d-%B-%Y")

with open("b.csv") as f:
    has_birthday = [user for user, birthday in csv.reader(f) if birthday == today]
    print(has_birthday)
```

Output:

```
['user1', 'user3']
```

You can add a custom message based on the length of has_birthday:

```
has_birthday = [user for user, birthday in csv.reader(f) if birthday == today]
frm = "{} have their birthdays today." if len(has_birthday) > 1 else "{} has their birthday today."
print(frm.format(" and ".join(has_birthday or ["Nobody"])))
```

So for one matching birthday:

```
userx has their birthday today.
```

For more than one:

```
userx and Usery have their birthdays today.
```

And for no user:

```
Nobody has their birthday today.
```

Comment: add `" and ".join(has_birthday)` for "and"'s between the names.

Comment: shouldn't it be `"...his\her..."` birthday and not `"....their..."` when its either one or none? Also is there a reason `"Nobody"` is a list and not just a string ?

Comment: ok i checked the first script you gave and it just gives me [ ] as the output . My csv file structure is like this  Asala, 14-September-2016

Comment: So you have a space after the comma?If so you need to add `skipinitialspace=True` to the reader call

Comment: You are the man . Thanks Bro. Can you do me another favour . If i add another column (3rd One) in the csv file mentioning their gender ( M for male , F for Female ) . How to get he output like if the user is male 'Userx has his birthday today and if the user is a female 'UserY has her birthday today' and if theres more than one user Just ' Userx and User Y have their birthday today

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone , So after doing some work and after getting all your helps , i was able to resolve this

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now().date().strftime("%d-%B-%Y")

while True:
   with open("InputFile.csv") as d:
    has_birthday = [user for user, birthday, gender in csv.reader(d,skipinitialspace=True) if birthday == today]
   if len(has_birthday) < 1:
    exit ()
   else:
     with open("InputFile.csv") as f:

       has_birthday = [user for user, birthday, gender in csv.reader(f,skipinitialspace=True) if birthday == today]

     with open("InputFile.csv") as g:

       male = [user for user, birthday, gender in csv.reader(g, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True) if birthday == today and gender == 'M']

     with open("InputFile.csv") as h:

       female = [user for user, birthday, gender in csv.reader(h, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True) if birthday == today and gender == 'F']

     if len(has_birthday) == 1 and male:
       frm = "{} has his birthday today."
     elif len(has_birthday) == 1 and female:
       frm = "{} has her birthday today."
     else:
       frm = "{} have their birthdays today."

     test = (frm.format(" and ".join([", ".join(has_birthday[:-1]), has_birthday[-1]]))) if len(has_birthday) > 1 else frm.format(" and ".join(has_birthday))
     print test
```